# How to display text in center if use verticalText?

Tags: itext

**My code**

```
VerticalText vt = new VerticalText(writer.getDirectContent());
vt.setVerticalLayout(marginLeft + squareHeight, 1191.0f - marginTop, squareHeight, 3, 20);
vt.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(imgr.getText(), fontV);
p.setLeading(10);
vt.addText(p);
vt.go();
```

The result : Text is middle in vertical mode.

I want to display text is center in horizontal mode as below link:
[image]

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented, left, center and right align has a different meaning in the context of `VerticalText`. Left is top, center is middle and right is bottom.

With class `VerticalText`, you always write from right to left. There is currently no way to align the text as shown in the screen shot to the right.

However, you could work around this problem by adding the vertical text in simulation mode first and then calculate the number of lines that have been written.

See for instance the [VerticalText1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=202) example from my book. I have adapted the code of that example like this:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(
    "KozMinPro-Regular", "UniJIS-UCS2-V", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(bf, 20);
VerticalText vt = new VerticalText(writer.getDirectContent());
vt.setVerticalLayout(390, 570, 540, 12, 30);
vt.addText(new Chunk(MOVIE, font));
vt.go();
System.out.println(vt.getMaxLines());
vt.addText(new Phrase(TEXT1, font));
vt.go();
System.out.println(vt.getMaxLines());
vt.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
vt.addText(new Phrase(TEXT2, font));
vt.go();
System.out.println(vt.getMaxLines());
```

The output of the `System.out` calls is:

```
11
4
1
```

These numbers are the number of lines that are available after each `go()`.

We start with 12 lines as defined in the `setVerticalLayout()` method.
We add `MOVIE` and there are 11 lines left. We've defined a leading of 30, which means we've already consumed (12 - 11) x 30pt = 30pt.

Then we add `TEXT1` which is distributed over 7 lines, which take 7 * 30pt in width. In total we now have consumed (12 - 4) x 30pt = 240pt.

Finally we add `TEXT2` which is distributed over 3 lines. Only 1 line is left. The total horizontal width of all the text is 330pt (we had only 30pt left).

Now that you know this math, you can execute the `go()` method in simulation mode, calculate the width that was consumed and use that info to add your text for real at the desired position.

Comment: if i can get the width of text is displayed in verticalText, i will set exactly text's position. how can i do it? in addition to , don't have ways to display text vertical in center and middle of rect ?

Comment: There is currently no method to get that width. As I tried to explain: very few people have ever used `VerticalText`, hence very little development has been done in this area.

Comment: Aha, I looked at an old example, and I may have found a workaround. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is exactly a great example. Thanks for your share :)

Comment: how far is the default distance between two characters in verticalText mode (at vertical , not at horizontal)? Could i change the default value ?

Comment: That would be probably be defined by the leading at the `Phrase` level. I haven't tested this though...

Comment: I tested it and wasn't successy :(